# Could the colour of questions be changed to reflect that they have no upvoted answers?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

At the moment when you look at the main page of questions there are 3 different 
categories of questions differentiated by colour:

- **Questions with no answers**:

  [image: Questions with no answers]
- **Questions with answers but none accepted:**

  [image: Questions with answers but none accepted]
- **Question with accepted answer:**

  [image: Question with accepted answer]

I think it would be useful for there to be a difference between "questions that have answers but no upvoted answers" and "questions that have upvoted answers". I think it would encourage people to look at questions with no upvoted answers, which they may normally ignore looking at as it would seem there is already an answer. It may also encourage to look and vote on new answers.

As a note, the mobile version of the site already has this functionality, with the font colour different dependent on whether a question has answers with upvotes:

- **Answers but no upvotes**:

  [image: Answers but no upvotes]
- **Answers with upvotes**:

  [image: Answers with upvotes]
- **Question has accepted answer**:

  [image: Question has accepted answer]

Comment: This seems to be the same request as http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117973/163868

Comment: It is the same request.

Comment: If anyone thinks there is no difference: there *is* a subtle change, which I support.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ What is it? I have never seen this before.

Comment: Yeah I think that will encourage people to look at them if there's no upvoted answer. As many people, including me, ignore some question if there are answers in the first place.